# sql select where string matches pattern defined in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement like this:

```
Select * from A where name like 'a%' or name like 'b%' or name like 'j%' or name like ... etc
```

Is it possible to store a%, b%, j% in a table somewhere so I can more easily manage this list and convert my query to something like:

```
Select * from A where name like (Select * from StringPatternToMatch)
```

Comment: _No, it is not possible to wrap you multiple `like` clauses in one_.

Comment: A correlated sub-query where the result is used in a comparison (E.g LIKE) may not return more than 1 row. A JOIN is better!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM A 
    JOIN StringPatternToMatch patt ON A.name LIKE '%' + patt.pattern + '%';
```

Replace `patt.pattern` with the name of the column in your `StringPatternToMatch`

Comment: a) that's not how you concatenate strings. b) even if it were, you'd only end up searching for a single substring, rather than a bunch of different criteria

Comment: @pala_, it's a JOIN condition, i.e. every row in StringPatternToMatch will be used as LIKE pattern.

Comment: yeah i assumed inner, not cross. it's still broken syntax and relatively inflexible as far as adding or removing patterns to match

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regexp search instead.

```
select * 
  from A where name regexp '^[abjf]';
```

It's easier query to maintain than a ton of or'd likes.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6d86/1)

`'^[abjf]'` means match the start of the string (`^`), followed by any of the characters in the list (`[abjf]`). It doesn't care what comes after that.

Just add more letters to the list if you find names starting with them.